# install Azure SDK 2.7 for .net in azure web role using start up task

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

I want the web role to contain .net SDk 2.7 for azure once code is deployed. Startup tasks seem to be the way around but i am not getting how to use it to install azure .net sdk specifically. Is there anyway to install Azure SDK 2.7 for .net in azure web role using a start up task?

Comment: Why do you want 2.7 of the SDK *inside* the Web Role? You usually build the Web Role with the SDK.

Comment: @Nick: The web app that's gonna be deployed on web roles requires the sdk.